# Code first - navigation property with different name than class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have several cases where my navigation property is repeated in a class, or I don't want it to have the same name as the class it represents. Example:

```
public class Employee 
{   
   public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
   public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
   public DateTime Start { get; set; }

   public Guid ResponsibleId { get; set; }
   public virtual Employee Responsible { get; set; }

   public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
   public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }
}
```

When using EF Code First, it messes up the foreign keys, creates new ones with different names. How do I handle this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is your metadata definition? Or maybe you don't have one and rely solely on automatic conventions?

Comment: I am doing convention over configuration. But if configuration can help here, I am all ears.

Comment: When you say it "creates new ones with different names", what exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, which works:

```
public class Employee 
{   
   public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
   public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
   public DateTime Start { get; set; }

   public Guid ResponsibleId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ResponsibleId")]
   public virtual Employee Responsible { get; set; }

   public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
   public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to Wiktor for the comment that lead to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
public class Employee 
{   
  public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Project> ResponsibleProjects { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Project> OwnedProjects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
  public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
  public DateTime Start { get; set; }

  public Guid ResponsibleId { get; set; }
  public virtual Employee Responsible { get; set; }

  public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
  public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }
}

public YourContext : DbContext 
{

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
         .HasRequired(p => p.Owner)
         .WithMany(e => e.OwnedProjects )  
         .HasForeignKey(p => p.OwnerId );

     modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
         .HasRequired(p => p.Responsible)
         .WithMany(e => e.ResponsibleProjects )  
         .HasForeignKey(p => p.ResponsibleId );

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
```

Note how relations are defined for both ends and how I point what exact field is used as a foreign key.